# HTML centering problems

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
div {
    width: 320px;
    padding: 15px;
    border: 5px solid gray;
    margin:0 auto;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<table border="5" bordercolor="Grey" bgcolor="grey">
   <tr><td><div><font size="20"><font face="Helvetica"color="white"><center><b>£799<b><center></div></td></tr>

</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

I can't seem to centre the border. I've tried using *margin:0* auto; as well as "*margin-left: auto;*" and "*margin-right: auto;*" When I paste the code on my website, it appears differently. I would like to have a bigger box around the £799 streching side to side in the colour of grey.

Would appreciate some help and a explanation on why that is happening.

Thanks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/E34sc.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIMC3.png

Comment: what are you trying to center. the table?

Comment: Wow the `<font>` *and* `<center>` tags. I feel like I'm in 1995 all over again.

Comment: you mean this : http://jsfiddle.net/rq64smj1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body{   
           margin:0 auto;}

      .centeredDiv {
           width: 100%;
           margin:0 auto;
           background-color:gray;
           text-align: center;
           line-height:100px;
           height:100px;
           font-size:300%;
           color:white;
           font-family:"Helvetica";
           font-weight: bold;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="centeredDiv">£799</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello. This is great and well tidied. How could I go about stretching the grey across the whole length of the screen, regardless of the size of the users screen?

Comment: I assume the use of using 100% width is what sorted that out. But when I move this code into a HTML content block on my website it messes the whole layout of the website (I use a basic what you see is what you get web builder) Thanks for the help so far though.

Comment: Spot on! Thank you ever so much Giorgi!

Answer (score 0):

Try this [`JSFiddle`](http://jsfiddle.net/53tyh23w/):

```
<style>
    div {
        width: 320px;
        padding: 15px;
        border: 5px solid gray;
        margin:0 auto;
        font-size:20px;
        font-face:"Helvetica";
        color: #fff;
        font-weight:bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <table border="5" bordercolor="Grey" bgcolor="grey">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div>£799</div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: This didn't center for me.

Comment: In the JSFiddle it's centered, can you make a fiddle of your code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're after - but this works (tidied up the html/css a bit).  I left some of the css inline, assuming that you have other divs that might not need the same styles.

```css
div {
  width: 320px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: 5px solid gray;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center
}
```

```html
<table border="5" bordercolor="Grey" bgcolor="grey">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="font-size:20px; font-family:Helvetica; color:white"><b>£799</b>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try by this way......

```
<div class="container">
   Now It's OK !
</div>


body{
    background:#626262;
}
.container{
    text-align:center;
    display:table;
    background:#7E7E7E;
    width:320px;
    margin:0 auto;
    font-size:30px;
    color:#FFF;
    box-shadow:0 0px 5px #333; 
    min-height:300px /* optional*/
}
```

view the live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sarowerj/2yjw3dw7/)